# Efficient truncating string copy `str` to `[u8]` (utf8 aware strlcpy)?

Tags: string, utf-8, rust

While Rust provides `str.as_bytes`, I'm looking to copy a string into a fixed sized buffer, where only full unicode-scalar-values are copied into the buffer, and are instead truncated with a null terminator written at the end, in C terms, I'd call this a `utf8` aware `strlcpy` *(that is - it copies into a fixed size buffer and ensures its null terminated)*.

---

This is a function I came up with, but I expect there are better ways to do this in Rust:

```
// return the number of bytes written to
pub fn strlcpy_utf8(utf8_dst: &mut [u8], str_src: &str) -> usize {
    let utf8_dst_len = utf8_dst.len();
    if utf8_dst_len == 0 {
        return 0;
    }
    let mut index: usize = 0;
    if utf8_dst_len > 1 {
        let mut utf8_buf: [u8; 4] = [0; 4];
        for c in str_src.chars() {
            let len_utf8 = c.len_utf8();
            let index_next = index + len_utf8;
            c.encode_utf8(&mut utf8_buf);
            if index_next >= utf8_dst_len {
                break;
            }
            utf8_dst[index..index_next].clone_from_slice(&utf8_buf[0..len_utf8]);
            index = index_next;
        }
    }
    utf8_dst[index] = 0;
    return index + 1;
}
```

---

**Note):** I realize this isn't ideal since multiple `UCS` may make up a single glyph, however the result will at least be able to decoded back into a `str`.

Answer (score 4):

Rust's `str` has a handy method [`char_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices) for when you need to know the actual character boundaries.  This would immediately simplify your function somewhat:

```
pub fn strlcpy_utf8(utf8_dst: &mut [u8], str_src: &str) -> usize {
    let utf8_dst_len = utf8_dst.len();
    if utf8_dst_len == 0 {
        return 0;
    }
    let mut last_index = 0;
    for (idx, _) in str_src.char_indices() {
        if (idx+1) > utf8_dst_len {
            break;
        }
        last_index = idx;
    }
    utf8_dst[0..last_index].copy_from_slice(&str_src.as_bytes()[0..last_index]);
    utf8_dst[last_index] = 0;
    return last_index + 1;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0bdca1ca8da4afe0a137e81d591f6fec&version=stable&backtrace=0)

However you don't actually need to iterate through every character except when copying, as it turns out it's easy to find a boundary in UTF8; Rust has [`str::is_char_boundary()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.is_char_boundary).  This lets you instead look backwards from the end:

```
pub fn strlcpy_utf8(utf8_dst: &mut [u8], str_src: &str) -> usize {
    let utf8_dst_len = utf8_dst.len();
    if utf8_dst_len == 0 {
        return 0;
    }
    let mut last_index = min(utf8_dst_len-1, str_src.len());
    while last_index > 0 && !str_src.is_char_boundary(last_index) {
        last_index -= 1;
    }
    utf8_dst[0..last_index].copy_from_slice(&str_src.as_bytes()[0..last_index]);
    utf8_dst[last_index] = 0;
    return last_index + 1;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=713e8cc7298bc31351e49da68d70dca5&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write `let mut last_index = ::std::cmp::min(utf8_dst_len - 1, str_src.len());` for the second example? This way its not counting down one-by-one when the string is smaller then the `[u8]`?

Comment: Have a slight preference for this version of the second example, https://bitbucket.org/snippets/ideasman42/GqB8o - maybe its just personal preference, but it avoids running `is_char_boundary` when its not needed, making it more explicit when the string needs to be truncated.

Comment: I'd probably also return an `enum` with a different variant if it were truncated, but I decided that was out of scope here.

Comment: @ideasman42: Note that `is_char_boundary` is VERY simple (http://blog.vrinek.io/rust/doc/src/core/str/mod.rs.html#1553-1560), it's basically `byte < 128u8 || byte >= 192u8`.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: The `last_index > 0` is unnecessary in your while loop. if `last_index` is 0, then it's a char boundary because of `str` invariants.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, good point!  Though I'd have to add a comment to explain why it's not needed.

Comment: @Matthieu M. right, the point is more that the common-code-path for non-truncating string copying can be kept simple, so it may as well be: ( updated http://bitbucket.org/snippets/ideasman42/GqB8o )

Comment: @ideasman42: Maybe... to be honest I'm not sure which is more readable or which generates better code. I somehow do wish that there was a `str.truncate` method, to be honest, that would take care of that... though how to define whether it truncates before or after the character when it falls straight in the middle could make things "interesting".

Answer (score -1):

Based on Chris Emerson's answer and @Matthieu-m's suggestion to remove a redundant check.

```
// returns the number of bytes written to
pub fn strlcpy_utf8(utf8_dst: &mut [u8], str_src: &str) -> usize {
    let utf8_dst_len = utf8_dst.len();
    if utf8_dst_len == 0 {
        return 0;
    }
    // truncate if 'str_src' is too long
    let mut last_index = str_src.len();
    if last_index >= utf8_dst_len {
        last_index = utf8_dst_len - 1;
        // no need to check last_index > 0 here,
        // is_char_boundary covers that case
        while !str_src.is_char_boundary(last_index) {
            last_index -= 1;
        }
    }
    utf8_dst[0..last_index].clone_from_slice(&str_src.as_bytes()[0..last_index]);
    utf8_dst[last_index] = 0;
    return last_index + 1;
}
```

---

*@ChrisEmerson: I'm posting this since it's the code I'm going to use for my project, feel free to update your answer with the changes if you like and I'll remove this answer.*